# why I use Authorization with api get 403 in express?

Tags: node.js, express

This is my code with if cookies has Authorization I save it, or response 403
**in token.js**

```
   module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    console.log('verifyToken token=', bearerHeader)
    if (bearerHeader) {
        const bearer = bearerHeader.split(' ');
        const bearerToken = bearer[1];
        req.token = bearerToken;
        next();
      } else {
        // Forbidden
        console.log('Forbidden')
        res.sendStatus(403).send("A token is required for authentication");
      }
}
```

**in api.js**

```
    const verifyToken = require('../tools/token.js')

router.post('/metadata', verifyToken, async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('api token =', req.headers['authorization'])
    let config = { headers: { Authorization : 'Bearer ' + req.headers['authorization'] }} 
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(src + '/record/metadata', '', config)
        console.log('data=', res.data)
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(res.data))
    } catch(err){
        console.error(err)
        res.writeHead(401);
    }
})
```

and I get this err

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
at createError (C:\Users\qq861\rabbit-backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
at settle (C:\Users\qq861\rabbit-backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\qq861\rabbit-backend\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:269:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1334:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
```

when I use test API it has status 200 
but if I use  Authorization with other api like it response 403 
I want to know why I use Authorization  but also get 403 Forbidden..?

Comment: Im guessing 'Bearer ' + req.headers['authorization'] gets you 'Bearer Bearer <token>'?

Comment: but Authorization not has Bearer, just <token>

Comment: are you sure that you send an Authorization header? since `if(bearerHeader){` is falsy its not there

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  let loadedUser;
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (!user) {
      const error = new Error("A user with this email could not be found.");
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }
    loadedUser = user;
    const isEqual = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isEqual) {
      const error = new Error("Wrong password!");
      error.statusCode = 401;
      throw error;
    }
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        email: loadedUser.email,
        userId: loadedUser._id.toString(),
      },
      "somesupersecretsecret",
      { expiresIn: "1h" }
    );
    res.status(200).json({ token: token, userId: loadedUser._id.toString() });
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err.statusCode) {
      err.statusCode = 500;
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

After that, you have to create an Auth Middleware you may have to concentrate to create a Token when a user successfully logs in and you have to pay attention to how to split and check the JWT token

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.get('Authorization');
  if (!authHeader) {
    const error = new Error('Not authenticated.');
    error.statusCode = 401;
    throw error;
  }
  const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
  let decodedToken;
  try {
    decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, 'somesupersecretsecret');
  } catch (err) {
    err.statusCode = 500;
    throw err;
  }
  if (!decodedToken) {
    const error = new Error('Not authenticated.');
    error.statusCode = 401;
    throw error;
  }
  req.userId = decodedToken.userId;
  next();
};
```